Can not seed GWC with custom grid set
I'm following geoserver tutorial and tried adding few CRS to caching defaults, 
but still when I try to seed the images, I don't see these options in dropdown.

what might be the issue ?

Did you add the gridsets to the layer that you are trying to seed?

If you have an existing layer this will not be updated after changing the defaults. You need to manually add the grid set to the existing layer in the Tile-Caching tab of the layer. Afterwards the grid set gets available in the GWC menu.
